# Error:Warning It is not an absolute URI

Tags: glassfish-3

when I run the application in netbeans 8.0.1,It runs successfully but I get an error:Warning It is not an absolute URI.How can I solve this problem?  Please help me.

Comment: Use an absolute URI. You should have a read of this [Stack Overflow: How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).